# Send parameters and run bash from python

Tags: python, bash, shell, parameters, subprocess

I need some help running a bash script from within a python one. I have a program which sends in parameters to the python script (for example, "$1"). I want to run a bash script from within the python script, send it the parameters, then receive and print the bash's outcome (echo) in the python script. This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen('sorter.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
out, err = process.communicate()
print(out)
```

When I try to run it, though, I get this error: **/bin/sh: sorter.sh: not found**

When I change the arg to 'sh sorter.sh' I get **sh: can’t open ’sorter.sh’**

I know for sure that the bash script works... when I run it from shell and provide it with a file (sh sorter.sh /file/filed/files.jpg) it all goes perfectly. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: try using full path or ./sorter.sh

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems like there's no `sorter.sh` in current working directory. Specify absolute path of the script.

Replace following:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('sorter.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

with:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('sh /path/to/sorter.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

or:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['sh', '/path/to/sorter.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Or add the pertinent directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, that first one did it, duh. I had thought that the bash script being in the same directory as the python one would be enough. Evidently not!

Answer (score 0):

To send parameters that your Python script received to the bash script, you could use `sys.argv`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import check_output as qx

output = qx(["/path/to/sorter.sh"] + sys.argv[1:])
print output,
```

If you call the python script as `python-script a b c` then it calls `sorter.sh` with `a`, `b`, `c` parameters.

Note: the code expects that `sorter.sh` has an appropriate [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and *execute* permission (`chmod +x /path/to/sorter.sh`).

Comment: I tried running your script and was getting OSError: no such file or directory (even with the corrected full path to the sorter.sh). Then I tried to combine it with my original attempt, like so:     `import sys
import subprocess

print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)

process = subprocess.Popen(["sh /usr/local/sabnzbd/var/scripts/sorter.sh"] + sys.argv[1:], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = process.communicate()
print(out)` It all runs now, but the parameters still aren't being sent. Any further ideas? Would it be easier if I tried to send just one parameter to bash?

Comment: @Artfail: You should copy the code as is (except for the path to `sorter.sh`). What is the shebang (`head -1 sorter.sh`)? What are file permissions for `sorter.sh` (`ls -l sorter.sh`)?

Comment: The code was copied directly (and path fixed). The file permissions are 755 (`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`), and I've tried having the shebang as both `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/bin/env bash`; either way, I get the following:

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/sabnzbd/var/scripts/worksmac.py", line 5, in <module>
    output = qx(["/usr/local/sabnzbd/var/scripts/hasworked.sh"] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: And when I shebang as `#!/usr/bin/env bash` it returns `env: bash: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/sabnzbd/var/scripts/worksmac.py", line 5, in <module>
    output = qx(["/usr/local/sabnzbd/var/scripts/hasworked.sh"] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/sabnzbd/var/scripts/hasworked.sh', '/volume1/Storage Unit/^Complete']' returned non-zero exit status 127`

Comment: @Artfail: try the simplest possible `sorter.sh` e.g., `printf '#!/bin/sh\necho "$@"' > sorter.sh`